No shadows emitting object
I want to create an object that emits light to produce the correct shadows from my object on the ground plane. When I use a regular spotlight, the object in my scene casts a shadow on the ground plane. When I use a cylinder with an emission shader, my object is illuminated but there's no shadow on the ground plane. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
I have attached a screenshot of:

the object properties for the ground plane
the shader editor for the object
sun as light source
sphere as light source (no shadow)

Thanks in advance!





I reproduced the behavior and it is indeed surprising. The weird thing is that when you activate shadow catcher on the bright object, for no reason it starts to work but the bright object disappear (of course)

Yes it's weird. I don't want the light source to be visible, so this solution actually works great for me :) Thanks Romain!

omg haha your welcome

@RomainGuimbal Sounds like an answer to me. Could you post it as an actual answer below?

@OconOcon ... shadow is still generated, but very subtle ... you can see it if you set plane's color to almost black like 0,001 https://imgur.com/XyemzT7 (material is still calculated with shadow catcher so it affects a result). But there is still strong indirect light for some reason. Would be great to know why Romain's comment (set shadow catcher to emissive object) works :) It looks like SC on mesh light  makes material ignored to cast on other objects.

As @RomainGuimbal mentioned, enabling the shadow catcher for the emitting object solves the shadow issue, but the bright object disappears.
